# How to prevent Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) effectively in PHP

Tags: php, security, session, session-variables, csrf

I am trying to prevent [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) in [php](/questions/tagged/php) in the following way:

1. A `$_SESSION['token']` is generated at the start of each page. I already know that using `$_COOKIES` is completely wrong since they are send automatically for each request.
2. In each `<form>`, the following input: `<input type="hidden" name="t" value="<?php echo '$_SESSION['token']; ?>">` is appended.
3. The `$_SESSION['token'];` is validated with the `$_POST['t']`

Now I have several small questions:

- Is this a good way to prevent CSRF? If not please explain.
- When another page is opened as well that sets the same `$_SESSION` variable, the previous (still open) page becomes invalid, how to prevent this?
- For forms this method is clear, but how to handle normal links? Is it necessary to append the token to each link as well?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: There are ways you can harden this further (e.g. binding tokens to individual forms so they can't be reused in a different context, which is what our [anti-csrf](https://github.com/paragonie/anti-csrf) library does). But what you described is what most people do.

Comment: Thank you @ScottArciszewski for the link and suggestion, I would like to keep things in my own hands instead of relying on a third party library for this but it is a very good idea to even restrict it further.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a good way to prevent CSRF?

Yes. What this does is to force the client to do a GET on the form before it can do a POST to your form handler. This prevents CSRF *in modern browsers* since browsers will prevent client-side Javascript to do an XHR GET request to a foreign domain, so a 3rd party cannot imitate your form on their site and successfully get a valid token for the submission.

> When another page is opened as well that sets the same $_SESSION variable, the previous (still open) page becomes invalid, how to prevent this?

Allow several tokens to be valid at a time, keeping an array of valid tokens in the session. Alternatively, store no tokens at all and use a token signing scheme instead. I've dabbled in and explained that [here](https://github.com/deceze/Kunststube-CSRFP). Alternative 2: just use a single token for the whole session, without invalidating tokens. (tip o' the hat to @SilverlightFox in the comments)

> For forms this method is clear, but how to handle normal links? Is it necessary to append the token to each link as well?

No. You only need to protect POST requests since **presumably only POST requests can alter sensitive data** (wink wink nudge nudge, you're sticking to REST conventions, right?!) and XHR GET requests are already blocked browser-side.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and yes of course I check the validity, lets update my question to make that clear.

Comment: What is a convenient way to handle a number of tokens, can I use the page url for example (assuming that a user does not open the same page two times..)

Comment: I'd keep an array of `$token => $timestamp` values in the session; on each form submission `array_filter` that array to discard expired tokens, then check whether the token is valid with `isset($_SESSION['tokens'][$_POST['token']])`.

Comment: I don't understand why making GET before POST is necessary? Token validation could be done completely on server side before any data processing. Or I did misunderstand your suggestion about validating upon submit?

Comment: @Glapa The client needs to make a GET request in order to load the form which contains a valid token which they need to include in their POST request. By extension, OP should be careful not to divulge valid tokens via POST.

Comment: Ohh... I get it now and it make sense of course. Thanks!.

Comment: Note that your `important edit` is incorrect. An XHR POST cannot retrieve data in the same was as a GET cannot. The Same Origin Policy prevents the response from being read by the foreign domain. Also, you do not need an array of tokens - just use one CSRF token per session.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Ah, good point about the SOP. However, multiple open tabs will use the same session, but potentially different forms!

Comment: That's correct, but they can use the same CSRF token to protect them.

Comment: @SilverlightFox Assuming you're invalidating tokens after use, that will still get you into hot water if the forms are opened and submitted in the "wrong" order.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. No need to invalidate them after use. Simply tie them to the current session and let them live for the lifetime of the session.

Comment: @SilverlightFox OK, that's a sensible alternative.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF attack occurs when a hacker tries to send a fake request from an authenticated user. normally this attack occurs
in online shops or banks.

Prevent csrf attack in php we can:
1 = Create a check login function:
If the login session is set that is true Ok, if not false and return to login page.
2 = create a random makeToken hash function with: base64_encode(md5(microtime())) and save it into session and create a input hidden type with token name and the value with name Token's function.
3 = Create a checkTocken function and check it, if it is equall to makeToken function, and after that use unset function to unset the session, and create a new one.