# form submit security with php

Tags: php, security

I have users click on a link sent to their email that takes them to a form (say, register.php) to complete their registration.

I have a check upon form submission in register.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    //register user in database
}
```

My question is: could someone technically circumvent this formal registration process by simply creating a custom http POST request with $_POST['submitted'] set? If so, what's a good way to check for this? I have checks for someone trying to GET to the registration page in an unauthorized manner but I feel like someone POSTing to the page isn't secure enough. Should I even be worried about this if I decide to use HTTPS? I hope this makes sense. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could always add a random token to the query string that you've generated and stored before sending to the email recipient. When they click on the link verify the token is in your white list.

Comment: _could someone technically circumvent_... :- Yes. _what's a good way to check for this?_ :- generate a random token, sent it with the email, and check that. _if I decide to use HTTPS?_:- what https has to do with this?

Comment: yes, anyone can build a custom form and "run" it from anywhere. all they need is some html that says `<form action="http://yourserver.example.com" method="post">`. boom... post submission to your server, without having originated anywhere from your stuff.

Comment: d'oh! I already generate and check against a hash (in the link) if someone is trying to GET to the page so I figure I'll just pass said hash along in a hidden form field to POST as the only person who knows what that hash is is the person who has that email account. I think that will work... Let me know if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue you describe is called cross-site request forgery. The attack can be prevented by generating a token, and setting the value of a hidden input in the form to the token. Also, set a session variable to the token value. In your PHP form receiving the post data, check if the session token and the sent token match. If they match, the form came from your site.

Here is another stack overflow question that includes more details about preventing Cross-Site Request Forgery: [How to prevent Cross-site request forgery (CSRF) effectively in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33776062/how-to-prevent-cross-site-request-forgery-csrf-effectively-in-php).

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to install a captcha

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html